# How to use morphOne?

Tags: laravel

I have 4 model ( media, convention, circle, status ). I think it will return data from 3 model ( convention, circle, status ). each media only have 1 convention, circle, and status. but empty.

media_data table

```
id
media_id
data_id
data_type
```

media model

```
public function data(){
   return $this->morphTo();
}
```

convention, circle, status model

```
public function media(){
  return $this->MorphOne(Media::class, 'data', 'media_data', 'data_id', 'media_id');
}
```

controller

```
$media = Media::first();

return $media->data;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations)?

Comment: @Unflux i look in already. the problem i want to set manually the key. what the table i point. If i just add the relation. it works as expected.

Comment: Why would you want to manually set the keys if the relation works without them?